# Msg 601... "Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement".BUT NOLOCK ! - BUG

Tags: sql-server

Strange situation... New physical severs, new install of SQL Server 2019 Enterprise version :
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ).
Testing the performance by creating the first database like this :

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_BENCH
GO

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'ALTER DATABASE DB_BENCH MODIFY FILE (NAME = ''' + name + N''', SIZE = 10 GB, FILEGROWTH = 64 MB);' 
FROM DB_BENCH.sys.database_files;
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'ALTER DATABASE DB_BENCH SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;'
EXEC (@SQL);
GO
```

And the objects in the database like this :

```
USE DB_BENCH
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

CREATE TABLE T_TIME_INTERVAL_TIV
(TIV_ID       INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
 TIV_GROUP    INT,
 TIV_DEBUT    DATETIME2(0),
 TIV_FIN      DATETIME2(0))
GO 

TRUNCATE TABLE T_TIME_INTERVAL_TIV;
GO

BULK INSERT T_TIME_INTERVAL_TIV
FROM "C:\DATA_SQL\intervals.txt"
WITH (KEEPIDENTITY , 
      FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
GO

CREATE VIEW V
AS
SELECT TIV_GROUP AS id, TIV_DEBUT AS intime, TIV_FIN AS outtime
FROM   T_TIME_INTERVAL_TIV
GO
```

The intervals.txt datafile contains 1 million lines.
You can have it at :
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AqvZfiQYoNpBiCD65D4zaRbch5s-?e=UicEYu

The query that produce the bug :

```
WITH T1 As
(SELECT id, intime 
 FROM   @T
 UNION  ALL
 SELECT id, outtime FROM @T),
T2 As
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY intime) NN, id, intime
 FROM   T1 T1_1),
T3 As
(SELECT T2_1.NN - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T2_1.id ORDER BY T2_1.intime,T2_2.intime) NN1,
        T2_1.id, T2_1.intime intime, T2_2.intime outtime
 FROM   T2 T2_1
        INNER JOIN T2 T2_2
              ON T2_1.id=T2_2.id
                 And T2_1.NN=T2_2.NN-1
 WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM   V S
                WHERE  S.id=T2_1.id
                  AND  (S.intime < T2_2.intime AND S.outtime>T2_1.intime))
    OR  T2_1.intime = T2_2.intime)
SELECT id, MIN(intime) intime, MAX(outtime) outtime
FROM   T3
GROUP  BY id, NN1
ORDER BY id, intime, outtime;
```

We tested this query on 2 different servers... with the same SQL Server installation.
The result is always :
*Msg 601, Level 12, State 1, Line ...
Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.*

With an installation of :
SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

There is no problem...

We tested the databases with DBCC CHECKDB () WITH DATA_PURITY. No errors.

Can you reproduce with your different editions/patches (CU) and give me your results for which are alright or  not ?

If some of you have already the bug I will add an entry in SQL Azure feedback...

Thanks

Comment: There is absolutly NO NOLOCK anywhere in this code as I mentionned in the title ! I know perfectly the danger of NOLOCK and wrote a paper available in french to avoid NOLOCK strategy !!! Here is my paper http://mssqlserver.fr/les-dangers-du-nolock/ (I was SQL Server  MVP for 15 years....)

Comment: You don't need to shout (!!!) @SQLPro, I can read your inside "voice" perfectly fine. As for my point, you don't actually state there is no `NOLOCK` and experience of users posting here has taught me far too many times that when they get an error and code that doesn't show it should means that they have code that they aren't showing us; hence my comment about `NOLOCK`, as the error suggests `NOLOCK` is there.

Comment: Just like when you see a user saying "I get  the error* 'Subquery returned more than 1 value' *but there is no subquery in my query `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable SELECT MyColumn FROM OtherTable;`"*. Such errors are because they have a trigger they haven't told us about. Hence my comment here there, and that there could be something you weren't telling us which *did* have `NOLOCK`.

Comment: to clear the point : in our tests, there is absolutly no concurrent user because we leave the firewall blocking access to SQL Server while processing our tests locally. There is also no extra code and no other objects created, only the code posted in this paper.

Comment: Your last query references a table variable  `@T`; what is that? Should it be replaced by the view `V`? If not, can you include the declaration and the `INSERT` for the data in the batch?

Comment: Is it possible your isolation level is `READ UNCOMMITTED`, perhaps through an SSMS default? (You can check by running `DBCC useroptions`)

Comment: Larnu :: the @T is a copy error. In fact it is the V view that is used in the code.

Comment: GarethD :: no more code except the one I post. So no specific isolation level like READ UNCOMMITTED...

Comment: I have managed to run your query without error on the same version (albeit the express version) - `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor) `

Comment: GartehD :: the installation is completly new starting with a new physical machine for a new instance of SQL Server a installaing the last version of SSMS. Absolutly no parameter have been modified neither in SQL Server nor in SSMS. And, of course, SSMS is in the default READ COMMITTED isolation level.

Comment: Gareth :: I think only the Enterprise version have the trouble with the RTM level.... not sure of course ! I have tested it on two different machines with Developper edition and no trouble... !

Comment: I too, cannot repro this, running from Azure Data Studio: `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU5) (KB4552255) - 15.0.4043.16 (X64) 
 Jun 10 2020 18:25:25 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) <X64>`

Comment: Note that RTM is already out of date; you may want to bring it up to CU6 (the most recent one) and test again, just in case. That will be necessary if you want to register it as a new bug, in any case.

Comment: Even with `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`, the statement runs for me @GarethD . Was worth a go. Perhaps it's an issue with the RTM version, as I am running CU5. There were several "bugs" with the initial release.

Comment: We are currently installing the CU6 to see if that solve the problem... I will give some news after.... but it takes time !

Comment: @SQLpro, no errors for me with SQL 2019 Developer with CU6. The first step when a bug is suspected is to install the latest CU as that is what Microsoft support would suggest anyway.

Comment: I confirm that in version SQL Server 2019 ed. Enterprise CU 6 (**Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU6) (KB4563110) - 15.0.4053.23 (X64)   Jul 25 2020 11:26:55   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )**) we have the same problem.... I think that it can be disk controler of the machine that can do this. I will try to move the database to another disk...

Comment: Same problem appear in moving the database from D disk (SSD) to C disk (another SSD). The tempdb has been created on a NVMe disk... I suppose that is the problem. I will try to move the tempdb which is on E disk to  C or D disk.

Comment: The same problem appear in any file/disk configuration, enforcing my thought that it can be the disk controller of the LENOVO machine that is out...

Comment: What does `DBCC CHECKDB(DB_BENCH) WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY` tell you?

Comment: DBCC CHECKDB has been executed before posting in StackOverlow to eliminate a disk failure...

Comment: MS has acknowledged this problem and is all related with the RCSI mode. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4089819/kb4089819-time-out-error-when-using-availability-groups-in-sql-server

Comment: Note that this MS fix concern 2016 and 2017 but not 2019. We are on 2019... and we do not use optimistic locking nor any AlwaysOn availability group on this instance...

Answer (score 4):

After many investigation, we found that it is really a SQL Server bug.

The bug disappear when we execute a :

```
UPDATE STATISTICS T_TIME_INTERVAL_TIV WITH FULLSCAN;
```

Or when whe "hint" the query with `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`

Sometime a stack dump appear (not Always) showing this type of messages :

*A time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch -- type 4, bp 0000029BA883BDC0, page 9:407, stat 0x10b, database id: 2, allocation unit Id: 422212465393664/140737488683008, task 0x0000029B86723848 : 14, waittime 300 seconds, flags 0x1a, owning task 0x0000029B86713848. Not continuing to wait.*

Which is the tempdb. A Stack Dump is systematically recorded on file.

We will call the MS hotline as soon as possible.

Thanks to all of you.